# Conditionally display different images before the content in a page template

Tags: templates, page-template

A few pages share a common template. Each of these pages need different images placed above the main content area. How do I do this?

The images need to appear above the editable region (ie WYSIWYG editor) because the images need to extend all the way from left to right.

Edit:

I am thinking of doing something as below in my template code. I am using a specific template plugin that also allows me to add specific markup along with the images so that I can style the images in different ways. Let me know if the following approach is fine or is there a better way to deal with this without having to hard-code the page ids directly into the template?

```
if(is_page(10)) {
  echo do_shortcode('[plugin_shortcode 1 .....]');
} else if (is_page(11)) {
  echo do_shortcode('[plugin_shortcode 2 .....]');
} else if (is_page(15)) {
  echo do_shortcode('[plugin_shortcode 3 .....]');
}
```

Comment: Template thing is a front-end thing, and WYSIWYG Editor is the back end thing. You failed to inform us about your actual scenario, I'm afraid. Please [edit] and add more detail so that we can understand your context.

Comment: Are you asking how to have a page template that's on multiple pages but is using different images/content? If you are, why not use the_post_thumbnail above the_content on your template? If that's not what you meant, as Mayeenul said, you'll need to provide more clarification. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: @RachieVee I could use `the_post_thumbnail` but I need to load multiple images and also need specific markups around the images. Please see my edit above and let me know if there is a better way to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: You can also try custom fields - does each page have the same amount of images? Also, is there any reason why you're using a shortcode rather than html and php for the images? Take a look at ACF and see if maybe it can be helpful to you: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: @RachieVee Thanks. ACF plugin has worked quite well for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the loop_start hook depending on what position you want the image and use the code in your functions file.

```
add_action('loop_start', function() {
if(is_page(10)) {
  echo do_shortcode('[plugin_shortcode 1 .....]');
} else if (is_page(11)) {
  echo do_shortcode('[plugin_shortcode 2 .....]');
} else if (is_page(15)) {
  echo do_shortcode('[plugin_shortcode 3 .....]');
}});
```

Or you could pull the images from your images folder and wrap each in a unique class.

```
add_action('loop_start', function() {
if(is_page(10)) {
   echo '<img class="image-one"><img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/one.png" /></img>'; 
} else if (is_page(11)) {
   echo '<img class="image-two"><img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/two.png" /></img>'; 
} else if (is_page(15)) {
   echo '<img class="image-three"><img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/three.png" /></img>'; 
}});
```

Or hard code the images into your template file.